# IEEEeqnarray: How can I force the number to follow the sections?

Tags: equations, numbering

When using `IEEEeqnarray`, the numbering of the equations starts at 1.  I would like the numbering to follow the sections.  For instance, an equation in section 1 will go 1.1, 1.2, ...

Is there something I need to add to the preamble to achieve the desired result?

```
\documentclass{article}
preamble
....
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
 & &
\end{IEEEegnarray}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably after the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}% Equation number format
\numberwithin{equation}{section}% Equations are number inside (and reset at) section
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
 a & b & c \label{abc}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\section{Another section}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
 x & y & z \label{xyz}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
See~\eqref{abc} and \eqref{xyz}.
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\numberwithin{<slave>}{<master>}` that allows you to specify whether a counter `<slave>` is reset with every `<master>` increment. The redefinition of `\theequation` updates the way the equation prints, which now includes `\thesection.` prepended.